# Does file /etc/apt/sources.list.apt-clone exist and if so, what is the difference to /etc/apt/sources.list?

Tags: apt, package-management

I know that `/etc/apt/sources.list` is used to tell the apt ubuntu/debian package system about the packages it should use. This is quite clear already.

But I have seen that there is a file `/etc/apt/sources.list.apt-clone` and I was wondering what it is? Is this file only present on my system (which is 12.04 precise)?

It seems indeed to be a copy of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

In case the file exists in all 12.04 versions, what purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file was created by `apt-clone`:

> apt-clone is the command-line tool for handling packages, and  may  be
>          considered  the  user's "front-end" to the apt-get(8). It manages GRUB
>          menu and ZFS 'syspool' filesystems. Two upgrade methods supported:  1)
>          safe  upgrades via cloning a currently active filesystem and later ch-
>          rooting into it to  perform  actual  upgrade  operation;  2)  in-place
>          (live)  upgrades  by checkpointing a currently active filesystem prior
>          to any upgrade modifications done by apt-get utility.

In one moment you used, or your OEM used apt-clone for cloning your current packages, and that file was left behind. If you don't use `apt-clone` anymore you can delete it without problems.

Comment: Great! how did you find out about that? man apt-clone did work? I thought via `apt-file search sources.list` it would tell me the package that does have sources.list.apt-clone. But since as you explained the file seems to be created dynamically and is not a part of the deb, it was not found. Anyhow thanks a lot! great answer